# Bluetooth thread / Handler doesn't update the UI

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-handler

I have an android app that receives values from a Bluetooth device. Everything works smooth and nice the first time I open the `Activity`. The value from the `Bluetooth` is shown in a `TextView`.

The app consists of two activities --> `Main` and `Details`(details includes a few fragments).

In `Main` activity, the user enters an ID and presses okay button. Then I start the Bluetooth thread and directly connect to a Bluetooth device using the MAC address. And then I open the `Details` activity.

In `Details` activity, I've made a `Handler` class that puts the value from the Bluetooth device to the text view. Then the users has yes and no buttons that save the value (or don't) in the database, when pressed and he is redirected back to the `Main` activity.

The first time this happens, everything works great. But the second time the `Details` activity is opened, the handle doesn't update the `UI`. I cannot understand why, if I try to debug, I can see that it works as it should -> the handler gets the value and updates the text views, but for some reason I can't see them in the `UI`.

Does anybody have any ideas what the problem might be?

The `Handle` looks like that:

```
static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<DetailsFragment> mFragment;

    public MyHandler(DetailsFragment fragment) {
        mFragment = new WeakReference<>(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        DetailsFragment fragment = mFragment.get();
        if (fragment != null) {
            String tempValue = (String) msg.obj;
            if (tempValue != null && !tempValue.equals("")) {                   
                fragment.updateTextViewValue(tempValue.trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is cancel button click in the `Details` activity:

```
public void cancelButtonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

This is the Bluetooth `ConnectedThread`:

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

    private final int INCOMMING = 1;

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    private final Handler mHandler;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, Handler handler) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        mHandler = handler;

        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams using temp objects, because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //log exception
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // buffer store for the streams
        int bytes = 0; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer[bytes] = (byte) mmInStream.read();
                if ((buffer[bytes] == '\n') || (buffer[bytes] == '\r')) {
                    String value = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(INCOMMING, value).sendToTarget();
                    bytes = 0;
                } else
                    bytes++;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //log the exception
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // log the exception
        }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if maybe when I open the `Details` activity for second time, the `ConnectedThread` and `Handler` are updating the old `TextView`, but is that possible, since I am using a `WeakReference` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it right, I just had to cancel the `ConnectThread` and `ConnectedThread` when I redirect back to the `MainActivity`. This fixed my problem. Embarrassing, but I am still a beginner.

However, I guess I still have a problem with the leaked activities. But that's another topic that I'll continue fighting with.

Answer (score 1):

Your description makes me think you may have a leaked activity, your thread would then update a fragment which is not displayed anymore. 
You may try to launch the following command line:

```
adb shell dumpsys meminfo <your.app.package>
```

You will find a good explanation of the result [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html).
What is interesting for you is found in the "Objects" section, where you will find an "Activities" number.

You may go that your Details activity, come back to the Main one, go again in Details, etc... 
The activites number should stay stable. If it increases, you may have a leak on your activity.

From there, you should look for retained views / fragments (I could see you had a WeakReference in your handler, so you know how to fix it)

Here, the profiling tools such as the [Memory Monitor](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html) and the [Allocation Tracker](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/performance/allocation-tracker/index.html) will surely help, but they take some time fto be understood.

Comment: You might be right about the leaked activity, but I cannot find out. I tried running the above command, but I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Well should that be right, you are on the verge of an epic fight. I will update my answer to give you more ammo...

Comment: "you are on the verge of an epic fight" - story of my life... Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: No problem, I've been through that many times, I know it's a tough one.

Comment: I think you are right about the leaked activity, I can see that going back and to the `Details` activity increases the number every time I start it again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't actually *update* the `Handler` of the `ConnectedThread`, the question isn't "why doesn't the UI update?" but rather, "how *could* the UI update?"

You'll need to update the thread's `mHandler` member:

```
public void setHandler( MyHandler newHandler ) {
    mHandler = newHandler;
}
```

and then add

```
connectedThread.setHandler( new MyHandler( this ) );
```

to your fragment's `onActivityCreated()` event.

Depending on how much traffic you have coming across, an event bus might be a better implementation.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't change anything. The thing is that the first time I start the activity, the UI is updated. The second time it's not. The app doesn't crash or anything, the code is going and if I debug, I can see that the Handler is getting the right messages, but the UI is not updated.